# Invalid initializer : strcat(s,str); in C program

Tags: c, string, strcat

I am writing program in hackerrank and trying to concat two strings using `strcat()` function but it is not working for me.

I am student and learning C language, can you help me to find way to concat two strings.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";

    // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
    int j;
    double e;
    char str[] = "";

    // Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
    scanf("Enter integer : %d",&j);
    scanf("Enter double : %lf",&e);
    scanf("Enter string : %s",str);

    // Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
    int sum = i + j;
    printf("\n %d",sum);

    // Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
    double doubleSum = d + e;
    printf("\n %lf",doubleSum);

    // Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
    char finalString[] = strcat(s,str);
    printf("%s",finalString);

    // The 's' variable above should be printed first.
    return 0;
}
```

**Error :**

```
solution.c: In function ‘main’:
solution.c:30:26: error: invalid initializer
     char finalString[] = strcat(s,str);
                          ^~~~~~
```

[Compiler Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJHY.png)

Comment: `strcat` is returning pointer. You can't initialize arrays with a pointer.

Comment: This might be a good time to read up on how to allocate memory for C strings. The code is riddled with errors in that area, and you'd save yourself time if you figure it out sooner rather than later.

Comment: Can we convert pointer to array, as I do not have much knowledge of pointer.

Comment: Well, that is indeed an invalid initializer. The only legal initializers for а `char []` array in C are: 1) string literal, 2) `{ ... }` initializer.

Comment: @nisheethposhiya: In which case this might also be a good time to read up on pointers. If you're going to be coding in C there's no way around understanding them.

Comment: Ok let me understand pointer first, thanks all for your inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    char *finalString = NULL;
    int j;
    double e;
    char str[100];
    scanf("%d",&j);
    scanf("%lf",&e);
    scanf("%s", &str);
    int sum = i + j;
    printf("\n %d",sum);
    double doubleSum = d + e;
    printf("\n %lf",doubleSum);
    finalString = realloc(finalString, strlen(s) + strlen(str) + sizeof(char));
    strcat(finalString,s);
    printf("\n %s",finalString);    
    strcat(finalString,str);
    printf("\n %s \n",finalString);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution, rather than just dumping code.

Comment: For the code itself, why do you use `realloc` rather than `malloc` when there is no re-allocation being done?  Also, instead of making successive calls to `strcat`, you can save the results of `strlen` to be used as an offset for `strcpy` rather than traversing through the string time and time again (which is what `strlen` does to get the length, and `strcat` does to find the end of the string).

Comment: Your answer is working in my editor but it fails in Hackerrank. i don't know which use cases it considering.

Comment: I was facing error due to new line and fixed it by adding extra scanf to scan new line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

strcat returns a char * which is a mutable pointer.  It can't be used as initialization of an array of characters because the size is not known at compile time.

It should also be noted that the first parameter you pass to strcat is the destination which is modified by the call and is what is returned.  For this to work your destination needs to have a big enough buffer to hold the contents of the combined string.

Comment: It could also be noted that for almost any input string the code will hit undefined behaviour even before getting to `strcat()` (*if* it gets to `strcat()` :)).

Comment: Thanks man, I am finding pointer bit difficult to understand. Thanks for your help.
Can you suggest some code to solve my error ?

Comment: Take a look at the link.  When you are dealing with strings you allays need to have enough space to store the value.  When you define the char arrays as you have the compiler only allocates what is required to store the literal.  You need to have more then that since any string sscanf finds will require more space than empty string.   Take a look at the link you can see how they define there char arrry as a hint. 


http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/