# Concanating 2 strings with a function in C

Tags: c, string, function, concatenation

I am trying to write a function where it concatenates `str1 and str2` with the `strncat`function. I am trying to get the `hello buddy` to be outputted within the `main` function. However it is giving me the `error: invalid initializer`.

function:

```
char result[100];
char* concanate(char b[],char c[]){
    char result[100]= strncat(b, c,20);
    return result;
}
```

main:

```
int main(void) {

    //Concanating two strings
    char result[100];
    const char str1[]= "hello";
    const char str2[]= "buddy";

    result= concanate(str1,str2);
    printf("%s",result)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`strncat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) "*returns a copy of dest*", which is a `char` *pointer*. You can't assign that to a `char` *array* like `result[100]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid initializer : strcat(s,str); in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706456/invalid-initializer-strcats-str-in-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you would create another function just to call `strncat()` but an easy fix would be to just return the pointer.`strncat()` returns a pointer `str2`, so you can't just save the result into an array.

Bare in mind `strncat()`, appends `str2` in `str1`, doing that, requires sufficient space in `str1` to be able to hold `str2`. This will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

char* concanate(char b[],char c[],size_t N){
    return strncat(b, c,N);
}

int main(void) {

    //Concanating two strings
    char *result;
     char str1[MAX_LEN]= "hello";
     char str2[]= "buddy";

    result = concanate(str1,str2,MAX_LEN-2); /* Saving space for the NULL byte */
    printf("%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

- Edit

If your aim is to re-implement `strncat()`, here is a sample:

```
#include <assert.h>

char *ms_nconcat(char *dst,const char *src,size_t len)
{
  char *temp = dst + strlen(dst); 

  assert(dst && src); /* check for null pointers */

  while ((*temp++ = *src++) && len--)
    ; 
  *temp = '\0'; /* null terminate dst */

  return dst; /* return a pointer to the first element of dst */
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but how is this an answer? You're not even reimplementing `strncat()`

Comment: `#define concatenate strncat` would have been exactly the same

Comment: @JackLilhammers I fixed OP's code, as to your second concern, you are right, I should have included a `strncat()` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, `concatenate` takes a destination buffer and its maximum capacity as parameters, along with the two strings you wish to concatenate into it.

- I can't use a local buffer declared in the function, because it'll go away when the function returns.
- I don't want to use a global buffer coded into the function, because if the function gets called again, the buffer will be overwritten.

This is why I'm choosing to have the caller specify where he wants the destination to go.  The caller also supplies the length, to ensure the results don't overflow the supplied buffer, a source of crashes and security holes.

```
char* concatenate(char dest[], int maxlen, const char b[], const char c[]){
    dest [0] = '\0';
    strncat (dest, b, maxlen);
    maxlen -= strlen (dest);
    // If space remains, add c.
    if (maxlen > 0) {
        strncat (dest, c, maxlen);
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    //Concatenating two strings
    char result[100];
    const char str1[]= "hello";
    const char str2[]= "buddy";

    concatenate(result, sizeof (result) - 1, str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Beyond that, I've tried to stay close to your approach.